# Ubuntu 12.04.3 installer stopped on activation (wlan0) stage 4 of 5 (ipv6 configure timeout)

Tags: installation, vaio

I have Sony Vaio laptop with Windows 8 preinstalled. I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 alongside Windows 8. I have made the bootable flash drive and ran Ubuntu live from it. I clicked on the **Install Ubuntu** icon on desktop, completed all the formalities. Now after downloading everything the installer is stuck on the following message:

```
ubuntu network manager[2107]: info Activation (wlan0) stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 configure timeout) completed.
```

What should I do? I am installing Ubuntu for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the boot options? I had pre installed windows 8 on my laptop too, and I had to change the boot priorities and edit the partitions.